# ArrayList.add() Method overwriting previous entires in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a project which acts as a relatively simple data type for Climbing Harnesses. The error I'm getting at the moment revolves around the ArrayList.add() method, it is currently overriding the previous enteries in the ArrayList, any help on a solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HarnessRecords {

```
public static ArrayList<Harness> harnesses;
private static int count =0;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HarnessRecords newRecords = new HarnessRecords();
    newRecords.addHarness("DXT", 3566, 0, "John Simons", false, "" );
    newRecords.addHarness("XTR", 663, 0, "James Glass", false, "");
    newRecords.addHarness("DVT", 616, 0, "King Charles", false, "");
    System.out.println((harnesses.get(0)).descriptionOfHarness());  
    System.out.println((harnesses.get(1)).descriptionOfHarness());
    System.out.println((harnesses.get(2)).descriptionOfHarness());

}public int addHarness( String modelType, int modelNumber, int numberOfTimesUsed, String instructorCheck, boolean isOnLoan, String hiredBy){
    Harness newHarness = (Harness) new Harness(modelType, modelNumber, numberOfTimesUsed, instructorCheck, isOnLoan, hiredBy );

    harnesses.add(newHarness);
    return (harnesses.size()-1);
}
```

Currently outputting
"The harness DVT 616, has been used 0 times it was last checked by King Charles and is not currently on loan

The harness DVT 616, has been used 0 times it was last checked by King Charles and is not currently on loan

The harness DVT 616, has been used 0 times it was last checked by King Charles and is not currently on loan"

Comment: Is it possible to see your Harness class? My bet is that the fields in your class are static... Also why a cast in your addHarness method? It's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all the fields in fields in `Harness` instance variables rather than `static` to ensure that there is a value per instance of the class